# Tkinter not displaying default Entry variable until button is added

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI in Python 3.9.1 with tkinter and am having issues getting a default value to show in an Entry box.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root, *args):
        self.root = root
        self.initial_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        self.initial_frame.grid(row=0)

        ttk.Label(self.initial_frame, text="User question here?").grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.ext_len = StringVar(value=4)
        ext_len_entry = ttk.Entry(self.initial_frame, textvariable=self.ext_len)
        ext_len_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

root = Tk()
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Note: official tkinter docs say to use `from tkinter import *` and `from tkinter import ttk`.
See this link and look in the Python section in the step-by-step walkthrough https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html

I've also tried using `self.ext_len.set(4)` after initializing the entry but before putting it on the grid. I've tried `self.ext_len.insert(0,4)` as well.

If I add a button with a callback that does nothing, the 4 shows up in the entry box. I found that I don't even have to render it on the grid. Just initializing it is enough. A button without a callback does not work.

Working code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root, *args):
        self.root = root
        self.initial_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        self.initial_frame.grid(row=0)

        ttk.Label(self.initial_frame, text="User question here?").grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.ext_len = StringVar(value=4)
        ext_len_entry = ttk.Entry(self.initial_frame, textvariable=self.ext_len)
        ext_len_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

        ttk.Button(self.initial_frame, text="Test button", command=self.test_func)

    def test_func(self, *args):
        pass

root = Tk()
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Why does initializing the button cause it to work?

Comment: Your `StringVar` is referenced only by your instance of `GUI`, and you aren't saving any reference to that instance, so the Var gets garbage-collected before the Entry gets displayed.  Try `gui = GUI(root)` instead.  (Having a Button with a callback helps because the callback has a reference to `self`, thus keeping the GUI instance alive.)

Comment: That makes sense! I changed it to how you recommended and it works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: _"Note: official tkinter docs say to use from tkinter import * "_ ... and PEP8 says to not use wildcard imports. Personally, I agree with PEP8.

Comment: [TkDocs.com](https://tkdocs.com/) are not the official `tkinter` docs. There aren't any, really.

Comment: @martineau I think the `help(tkinter)` could be considered pretty official (it at least somewhat describes the methods) since it is literally from the source code. Also aren't these https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html the official docs (which btw also suggest the same import pattern (which is interesting since PEP 8 suggests otherwise (I guess those docs have never been changed since written)))